# Como criar várias pastas com mkdir

Tags: php, sistema-de-arquivos

Olá, gostaria de saber como criar várias pastas de uma vez, por exemplo, com esse código:

```
<?php
        $empresa = "Google";
        $tipo = "Abertura";
        $nome = "Contrato Social";

        mkdir('$empresa/$tipo/$nome');
?>
```

Agora com esses dados gostaria de criar nesse caso 3 pastas que seria a
 Google -> Abertura -> Contrato Social, no caso a google é a pasta mãe e abertura está dentro dela, e contrato social é outra pasta que está dentro de abertura, que está dentro de google, ficou meio confuso mas seria algo assim:

Empresas\Google\Abertura\Contrato social

EDIT:

Montei algo mais ou menos assim mas mesmo assim dá erro, ele não cria as pastas dentro, ele cria fora tipo Joaquim Sauro.FGTS

```
<?php
$nome_user = "Joaquim Sauro";
$tipo = "FGTS";
$categoria = "Abertura";
$pdf = "pdf.pdf";

$pathName = "html/empresas/" . $nome_user;

   mkdir($pathName,0777,true); 
    echo "OK1";

$pathName2 = "html/empresas/.$nome_user."/"" . $tipo;

    mkdir($pathName2,0777,true); 
     echo "OK1.1";

$pathName3 = "html/empresas/.$nome_user."/".$tipo."/"" . $categoria;

    mkdir($pathName3,0777,true);
     echo "OK1.2";

move_uploaded_file($pdf,$pathName3);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode ser por causa da intercalação de textos com variáveis, tente o código abaixo:

```
<?php
$nome_user = "Joaquim Sauro";
$tipo = "FGTS";
$categoria = "Abertura";
$pdf = "pdf.pdf";

$pathName = "html/empresas/{$nome_user}/{$tipo}/{$categoria}";
mkdir($pathName, 0777, true);
echo "OK";

move_uploaded_file($pdf, $pathName);
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

Além das respostas já citadas, se você utiliza `composer` e os componentes do `Symfony` você pode utilizar o `FileSystem`.

Este componente te permite fazer estas tarefas de criar diretórios, mudar permissões, mover arquivos, etc..., de uma forma independente de sistema de arquivos e sistema operacional. Assim seu código vai funcionar independente de estar rodando em Linux/Windows/BSD/etc.

Para instalar, utilize o comando:

```
composer require symfony/filesystem
```

Um exemplo básico de utilização:

```
include __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOExceptionInterface;

$fs = new Filesystem();

try {
    $fs->mkdir('empresa/tipo/nome');
    echo "deu tudo certo :)";
} catch (IOExceptionInterface $e) {
    echo "Um erro ocorreu ao gerar os diretorios ".$e->getPath();
}
```

Com este comando ele vai criar automáticamente os tres diretórios dentro da pasta atual. Caso os diretórios já existam, a rotina prossegue normalmente, sem dar nenhum erro.

Você pode olhar a documentação oficial [neste](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html) link.

Answer (score 0):

Defina o terceiro parâmetro da função com valor `true`.

Esse parâmetro indica que os diretórios não existentes serão criados recursivamente.

```
mkdir('foo/bar/folder/', 0777, true);
```

Claro que para informar o terceiro argumento é preciso definiro segundo que é referente a permissões de leitura e escrita. (chmod)

O código acima é um exemplo ilustrativo.

Answer (score 0):

Seu código tinha problemas de concatenação nas variáveis $pathNameX, eu corrigi e reutilizei as variáveis para facilitar.

```
<?php
$nome_user = "Joaquim Sauro";
$tipo      = "FGTS";
$categoria = "Abertura";
$pdf       = "pdf.pdf";

$pathName = "html/empresas/" . $nome_user;
mkdir($pathName,0777,true); 
echo "OK1";

$pathName2 = $pathName . "/" . $tipo;
mkdir($pathName2,0777,true); 
echo "OK1.1";

$pathName3 = $pathName2 . "/" . $categoria;
mkdir($pathName3,0777,true);
echo "OK1.2";

move_uploaded_file($pdf,$pathName3);
?>
```